# Changes necessary to make while solving this Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f(0)=0$. If $y=f(x)$ satisfies the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=(2+5y)(5y-1)$, then the value of $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$

This DE is pretty simple really and directly gives $x=\frac{1}{4}\ln (5y-2)-\frac{1}{4}\ln(5y+2)+\ln C$. However my only query is that the value of C comes out to violate log definitions. Which is why I had to make changes and make the quanities inside the log perfect squares. I want to know why does it not work without manipulations? Is it wrong to take the constant of integration as some $\ln C$?

Comment: You have an initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(y)=(2+5y)(5y−1)$ is positive for $y>\frac15$ and $y<-\frac25$ and negative on the interval in-between. Starting with $y_0=0$ the solution will thus fall between the constant solution at $\frac15$ at negative infinity towards the constant solution $y=-\frac25$ and get asymptotically ever close to the constant solutions in both directions.

Note that constant solutions are at roots of $F$, there can be no other constant solutions, no other solution can reach or cross a constant solution. Every other solution is monotonous with limits at one of the constant solutions or at infinity (possibly at a finite time).

---

Besides being separable, the right side is also a quadratic polynomial, which makes this a Riccati equation. For these one can parametrize $y=\frac{u}{v}$, which adds a functional dependency to the situation, which leads to
$$
u'v-uv'=(5u+2v)(5u-v)=25u^2+5uv-2v^2.
$$
This can now be split into terms with factor $u$ and terms with factor $v$, mixed terms can go to either group. For instance setting $u'=-2v$ leaves $-v'=25u+5v$, which combines to
$$
u''=2(25u+5v)=-5u'+50u \implies u=Ae^{-10x}+Be^{5x},~~2v=10Ae^{-10x}-5Be^{5x}
$$
Realize the initial condition via $u(0)=0\implies B=-A$, $v(0)\ne 0$, so that with $A=2$
$$
y=\frac{2e^{-10x}-2e^{5x}}{10e^{-10x}+5e^{5x}}
=\frac25·\frac{1-e^{15x}}{2+e^{15x}}
$$

Comment: I agree that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\frac{-2}5$, but the OP asked for $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$, which is equal to $\frac15$ (by your method as well as his, which I corrected).

Comment: Yes, that is true, I reformulated the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of your DE is rather
$$x=\frac1{15}\ln\left|\frac{5y-1}{5y+2}\right|+C$$
with $C$ given by
$$0=\frac1{15}\ln\frac12+C,$$
hence
$$x=\frac1{15}\ln\left|\frac{2(5y-1)}{5y+2}\right|,$$
which gives
$$f(x)=\frac{2(1-e^{15x})}{5(2+e^{15x})}\text{ and }\lim_{x \to-\infty}f(x)=\frac15.$$